# Aggregate a single table of SQL data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some data in SQL Server like:

```
[RaceNumber], [Make], [Model], [Driver], [Time], [MaxSpeed]
1, Mercedes, GTR, Joe Bloggs, 122, 150
2, Mercedes, GTR, Joe Bloggs, 124, 149
1, Porsche, Boxter, Fred Smith, 125, 140
2, Porsche, Boxter, Fred Smith, 130, 141
```

I want a query to give me a result like:

```
Mercedes, GTR, Joe Bloggs, 122, 150, 124, 149
Porsche, Boxter, Fred Smith, 125, 140, 130, 141
```

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

My only solution so far is to split the data into 2 temporary tables by [RaceNumber] and select from the 2 sources with a join.

Comment: Learning SQL, then trying something and when you have a specific problem come here and ask with code examples and what you have tried.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we are neither a code writing service, nor a "teach me sql, I have no idea how to even start" website.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this was quite an interesting problem. Let me re-write the question a bit with some real data to make it clearer.

Comment: You want to show the first two races per make, model, and driver in the results?

Comment: You don't need temporary tables for this, because you can select from a query, e.g. `select * from (select * from races where racenumber = 1) race1;` or `with race1 as (select * from races where racenumber = 1) select * from race1;`. Another solution is conditional aggregation. You'll find many examples for conditional aggregation in SO and on the Internet in general.

Comment: `select 'Mercedes', 'GTR', 'Joe Bloggs', 122, 150, 124, 149 union all ...;`. Or were we supposed to guess how to transform "I have" to "I want" with no explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You typically need to `GROUP BY` three string columns, and apply `STRING_AGG()` function for the last two column `[Time]` and `[MaxSpeed]` in the order of `[RaceNumber]` after `CONCAT`enating them :

```
SELECT [Make], [Model], [Driver],
       STRING_AGG (CONCAT([Time], ',',[MaxSpeed]), ',') WITHIN GROUP 
       (ORDER BY [RaceNumber]) AS [Time-MaxSpeed]
  FROM [tab]
GROUP BY [Make], [Model], [Driver]
```

provided your DB version is 2017+

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2c8503fa6535882014c2369520710b65)</kbd>